# aks-engine custom image for node pool using terraform

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am having a problem and need help, How to add custom vm image in to Aks cluster as a nodepool with vmscalset using terraform code in Azure,

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The AKS uses Ubuntu 16.04.LTS image as the host OS and there is no option to select an alternate operating system. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/security-hardened-vm-host-image#security-hardening-features).

If you want to use your own custom image, you can use the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine) instead and apply the [custom-image](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/examples/custom-image.json).